# What's the complexity of this algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, complexity-theory

Here is an algorithm counting occurrences of anagrams of one string (search_word) in the other (text):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<deque>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string text = "forxxorfxdofr";
    string search_word = "for";
    deque<char> word;
    word.insert(word.begin(), text.begin(), text.begin() +  search_word.size());
    int ana_cnt = 0;

    for (int ix = 3; ix <= text.size(); ++ix)
    {   
            deque<char> temp = word;
            sort(word.begin(), word.end());
            if (string(word.begin(), word.end()) == search_word)
                    ++ana_cnt; 
            word = temp;    
            word.pop_front();
            word.push_back(text[ix]);
    }   
    cout << ana_cnt << endl;
}
```

**What's the complexity of this algorithm?**

I think it's `O(n)` algorithm, where `n` is the length o text. This is because the amount of time needed to execute what is inside for loop is independent of the lenght of `n`. However, some think it is not `O(n)`. They say the sorting algorithm also counts when computing complexity.

Comment: You are sorting inside the loop, how is it O(n) ?

Comment: @0x90 Perhaps because he's sorting only a word, and not the entire text? Would that make it `O(n*m)`?

Comment: Its impossible that it was O(n) cos any sorting algorithm has at least O(nlogn) complexity, and you are doing that in the body of a loop, so the complexity of that algorithm is O(n^2logn) at least

Comment: @us2012 ok, its only other variable to consider: O(n*mlogm) which is O(n^2logn) complexity in any practical sense

Comment: As `m` is fixed (at `3` from `text.begin() + 3`), I think it's a constant factor and should therefore be ignored in big-O.

Comment: @us2012 its correct because O(n) notation measures how the cost (Memory,time,etc) grows depending on the size of the input, not measures the real cost. When we say "Has O(n) complexity" we don't say the algorithm takes exactly n comparisons (If was comparisons what you are using to measure the cost), means that the algorithm cost **grows** like (The cost is bounded above) a polynomial of the form p(n) = an + b

Comment: Everyone needs to define their variables when using big O() notation.

Comment: *Side remark*: `text.begin() + 3` should probably better be `text.begin() + search_word.length()`.

Comment: @us2012 They are not independent. `m` is bounded by `n`, i.e. m = O(n). Therefore O(nm log m) = O(n^2 log n). So yes, you are wrong. You’d be right for Θ, but O is an *upper* bound.

Comment: @Konrad, yeah - you and Manu are right, I have deleted my earlier comment. (I'd still like to question the point of giving upper bounds that aren't as sharp as you can make them). Would you ever give the complexity of a naive string search of size `m` in a text of length `n` as `O(n^2)`, even though it's technically correct?

Comment: @Konrad On second thought, I'm not sure I agree with your assessment that `m` is bounded by `n`. This implementation of the algorithm will crash for `m>n` as you can't initialize `word`, but very conceivably you could implement the same algorithm in a way that doesn't *fail* for `m>n`.

Comment: @us2012 You’re correct there. For that reason I intensely dislike the convention of equalling O-notation in computer science. More mathematically correct would be to use “∈” instead of “=” to make it clear that they are *not* equivalent. And yes, you should generally give bounds as sharply as possible. Regarding the case m>n, in a sane algorithm this would be caught with a simple check in O(1), or in the worst case after probing n characters.

Comment: Don't forget the `deque` copy c'tor to `temp`, copy back ( + d'tor on the previous value of `word`), destructor on `temp`...

Comment: @nmaier One would hope that those are at worst linear in the length of `word`/`temp`, which would mean that the loglinear sort of `word` dominates this.

Comment: Regardless of the complexity, you are accessing an out of bound character of your text with `text[ix]` when `ix = text.size()`.

Comment: @us2012 I agree, but since people here questioned the use of big-O and the question just asks for complexity in general, I thought I should mentioned them anyway because people might miss that these are not constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's `O(n)`** if you only consider the string `text` with length `n` as input.

Proof: You're looping over `ix` from `3` (probably `search_word.size()`, isn't it?) to `text.size()`, so asymptotically you execute the loop body `n` times (since there is no `break`, `continue` or modification of `ix` in the loop body).

The loop body is *independent* of `n`. It sorts a queue of *fixed* size, namely `m` = `search_word.size()`, that is `O(m log(m))` in the average case (worst case `O(m^2)`). As this is independent of `n` we're done with a total of `O(n)`.

**It's not `O(n)`**: If you want to be a little bit more precise, you'd probably count `search_word` with length `m` as input and this comes to a total of `O(n m log(m))` on average, `O(n m^2)` in the worst case.